# Preview PDF doesn't work in Safari but works in other browser

Tags: craft2, plugin-printmaker, dompdf

I'm trying to figure out why I am able to preview a PDF in all other browser apart from Safari. The PDF is generated using DOMPDF (printmaker plugin) and output to the browser though PHP using Craft CMS.

An example of the PDF is https://kendal.ac.uk/courses/2018.pdf

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think this question does not really belong here but I'll answer it anyway. Sarafi changed the way it displays PDF documents. You can see instructions from [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html) how to enable the browser view. Besides that you have not really a chance to force other Safari users to open PDFs in their browsers. You can as well see other multiple other discussions about it the [Apple Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8162544)

Comment: I really wasn't sure what stack exchange to put this in, there are just so many!
I get what you're saying.... My Safari browser opens other PDF documents generated by other craft websites fine, just not this one. So it's not an issue with the browser not understanding what to do with the PDF but more an issue with the generated PDF. I have compared response headers but I can't see anything.